# Read metadata from camera stream in python

Tags: python, camera, metadata

What i want to obtain is to get a constant stream of metadata from my webcam or from an ip camera.

I checked if i could take a frame and get some data from it, but to no avail.

EDIT

To clarify, what i have is:

- A livestream (it could be from my webcam or from an ip camera)

What i need is:

- To print the metadata of the livestream every second (it could even
  be of a frame per second)

an example of what i need:

```py
""" ExifTool Version Number : 11.63
File Name : imgMeta.jpg
Directory : /Projects/ImageMetaData/Images
File Size : 32 kB
File Modification Date/Time : 30
File Access Date/Time : 30
File Creation Date/Time : 30
File Permissions : rw-rw-rw-
File Type : JPEG
File Type Extension : jpg
MIME Type : image/jpeg
JFIF Version : 1.01
Exif Byte Order : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Make : Canon
Camera Model Name : Canon PowerShot S40
Orientation : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution : 180
Y Resolution : 180
Resolution Unit : inches
Modify Date : 44
Y Cb Cr Positioning : Centered
Exposure Time : 1/500
F Number : 4.9
Exif Version : 0220
Date/Time Original : 44
Create Date : 44
Components Configuration : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Compressed Bits Per Pixel : 5
Shutter Speed Value : 1/501
Aperture Value : 5.0
Max Aperture Value : 2.8
Flash : Auto, Did not fire
Focal Length : 103.7 mm)
Macro Mode : Normal
Self Timer : Off
Quality : Superfine
Canon Flash Mode : Auto
Continuous Drive : Single
Focus Mode : Single
Record Mode : JPEG
Canon Image Size : Large
Easy Mode : Manual
Digital Zoom : None
Contrast : Normal
Saturation : Normal
Sharpness : 0
Camera ISO : 100
Metering Mode : Center-weighted average
Focus Range : Auto
AF Point : Center
Canon Exposure Mode : Program AE
Lens Type : n/a
Max Focal Length : 21.3125 mm
Min Focal Length : 7.09375 mm
Focal Units : 32/mm
Max Aperture : 5
Min Aperture : 8
Flash Activity : 0
Flash Bits : (none)
Focus Continuous : Single
AE Setting : Normal AE
Display Aperture : 4.9
Zoom Source Width : 2272
Zoom Target Width : 2272
Spot Metering Mode : AF Point
Focal Type : Zoom
Focal Plane X Size : 7.26 mm
Focal Plane Y Size : 5.46 mm
Auto ISO : 100
Base ISO : 100
Measured EV : 13.63
Target Aperture : 5
Target Exposure Time : 1/501
Exposure Compensation : 0
White Balance : Auto
Slow Shutter : Off
Shot Number In Continuous Burst : 0
Optical Zoom Code : 6
Flash Guide Number : 0
AF Points In Focus : Center
Flash Exposure Compensation : 0
Auto Exposure Bracketing : Off
AEB Bracket Value : 0
Control Mode : Camera Local Control
Focus Distance Upper : 7.82 m
Focus Distance Lower : 0 m
Bulb Duration : 0
Camera Type : Compact
Canon Image Type : PowerShot S40 JPEG
Canon Firmware Version : Firmware Version 1.10
File Number : 117-1771
Owner Name : Andreas Huggel
Canon Model ID : PowerShot S40
User Comment : 
Flashpix Version : 0100
Color Space : sRGB
Exif Image Width : 2272
Exif Image Height : 1704
Interoperability Index : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Interoperability Version : 0100
Related Image Width : 2272
Related Image Height : 1704
Focal Plane X Resolution : 8114.285714
Focal Plane Y Resolution : 8114.285714
Focal Plane Resolution Unit : inches
Sensing Method : One-chip color area
File Source : Digital Camera
Custom Rendered : Normal
Exposure Mode : Auto
Digital Zoom Ratio : 1
Scene Capture Type : Standard
Compression : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset : 2066
Thumbnail Length : 5448
Image Width : 480
Image Height : 360
Encoding Process : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample : 8
Color Components : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling : 0 (2 2)
Drive Mode : Single-frame Shooting
ISO : 100
Lens : 34.5 - 103.7 mm)
Shooting Mode : Program AE
Aperture : 4.9
Image Size : 480x360
Lens ID : Unknown 7-21mm
Megapixels : 0.173
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent : 4.9
Shutter Speed : 1/500
Thumbnail Image : (Binary data 5448 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Circle Of Confusion : 0.006 mm
Depth Of Field : 2.17 m (3.11 - 5.28 m)
Field Of View : 19.7 deg
Hyperfocal Distance : 15.02 m
Light Value : 13.6 """
```

I tried:

- OpenCV (could not get anything even from a single frame)
- PyGame (same thing)
- PIL ExifTags (obviously it didn't work because the single frame doesn't have anything inside it)

Comment: What exact metadata do you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @L_Jay i added some details, thank you for your support